# Strict Mode Error on Android 5.0 in Nexus 7

Tags: android, httpclient

My app is running well on version below 5. But when i run it on Nexus 7 with version 5, it crashes with following error msg

```
12-02 18:24:01.941: E/StrictMode(14686): A resource was acquired at attached stack trace but never released. See java.io.Closeable for information on avoiding resource leaks.
12-02 18:24:01.941: E/StrictMode(14686): java.lang.Throwable: Explicit termination method 'close' not called
12-02 18:24:01.941: E/StrictMode(14686):    at dalvik.system.CloseGuard.open(CloseGuard.java:184)
12-02 18:24:01.941: E/StrictMode(14686):    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:78)
12-02 18:24:01.941: E/StrictMode(14686):    at com.android.okhttp.internal.DiskLruCache.get(DiskLruCache.java:417)
12-02 18:24:01.941: E/StrictMode(14686):    at com.android.okhttp.HttpResponseCache.get(HttpResponseCache.java:164)
12-02 18:24:01.941: E/StrictMode(14686):    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:190)
12-02 18:24:01.941: E/StrictMode(14686):    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:373)
12-02 18:24:01.941: E/StrictMode(14686):    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:323)
12-02 18:24:01.941: E/StrictMode(14686):    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:491)
12-02 18:24:01.941: E/StrictMode(14686):    at android.media.MediaHTTPConnection.seekTo(MediaHTTPConnection.java:199)
12-02 18:24:01.941: E/StrictMode(14686):    at android.media.MediaHTTPConnection.readAt(MediaHTTPConnection.java:315)
12-02 18:24:01.941: E/StrictMode(14686):    at android.media.MediaHTTPConnection.native_readAt(Native Method)
12-02 18:24:01.941: E/StrictMode(14686):    at android.media.MediaHTTPConnection.readAt(MediaHTTPConnection.java:304)
12-02 18:24:01.941: E/StrictMode(14686):    at android.media.IMediaHTTPConnection$Stub.onTransact(IMediaHTTPConnection.java:72)
```

Can anyone suggest solution for this.

Comment: Maybe you didn't close connection somewhere in your code?

Comment: I have closed the connections everywhere.

Comment: It is very possible that this is a bug in Android -- Google does not bother checking with `StrictMode` for their own code. If you can create a sample project that can reproduce the error, you could try filing an issue for it at http://b.android.com.

Comment: I'm getting a similar (but not identical) stack trace in my application using Android's [MediaPlayer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html). The stack trace does not reference my code so chalking this up to an Android bug especially since it appears to work in earlier versions.